# Revealing Module Pattern variable problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, revealing-module-pattern

I am new to web development and I recently discovered the revealing module pattern. But I am having problems implementing it in to my JS.

```
 var navigation = (function(){
    //chache DOM
    var $navBar = $('.navBar');
    var $navBtn = $('.navBar .btn');
    var $section = $('.section');
    var mobileNav = $('.navBarMobile');

    //bind events
    $('.navBar .btn').on('click', sectionScroll());
    //$navBtn.on('click', sectionScroll()); wouldn't run


    //select section via scroll pos.
    function selectScroll(){
        var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windscroll >= 10) 
        {
            $('.section').each(function(i)
            {            
                if ($(this).offset().top -200 <= (windscroll)) 
                {
                    $navBtn.removeClass('selected');
                    $navBtn.eq(i+6).addClass('selected');
                    $navBtn.eq(-i+5).addClass('selected');
                }
            });
        } 
     }

    //scroll to section via click
    function sectionScroll(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = $(this).find('a').attr('data-scroll');
        var offset = $('[data-anchor=' + target +']').offset().top - 100;
        TweenMax.to($('html, body').stop(), 1, {scrollTop: offset, delay:     .36});  
    }

    return {
        selectScroll: selectScroll
    };

    })();

    var main = function () 
    {
        $(window).scroll(function() { navigation.selectScroll(); }).scroll();
    }; 
    $(document).ready(main);
```

In my selectScroll function it wouldn't run correctly until I replaced "$navBtn" with "$('.navBar .btn')". Did I do something wrong when i declared the variables?

Also if I replace 
    `$navBtn.on('click', sectionScroll());`
with
    `$('.navBar .btn').on('click', sectionScroll());` 
the sectionScroll function kept giving me this error: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

EDIT:
I found the problem thanks to @Bergi on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element). My question is now what would be the best way to use this soulution along with the revealing module pattern? Would it be putting the defer attribute on the JS :
    `<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js" defer></script>`
or is there a better solution when using revealing module pattern?

Comment: This pattern is also called IEFE. The *immidiately executed* should be taken literally. The DOM has not yet loaded, using the module pattern does not relieve you from using `$.ready`.

Comment: Either just put the `$.ready()` call right within your module, around the things where you query the dom; or export an `init` method from your module that you'd then call in your app `main` startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is `sectionScroll()`. It should be `sectionScroll` without the parentheses.
With parens you are calling `sectionScroll` and then pass it's return value 
to `on`. As you called it without arguments, parameter `e` of `sectionScroll` would be of value `undefined` and you got the error.
Try this: `$('.navBar .btn').on('click', sectionScroll);`

Comment: That fixed the error but I don't think the function was being called after I made that change. The function wasn't working, after I made the change, so I commented everything in that function and put "console.log("hello")" and nothing was logged.